# Failed to Load "Intel Accelerator OpenSSL Engine"

Tags: openssl

We want to test the performance of this Intel Engine to see how much it can improve the openssl performance.

We compile openssl 1.0.0 by default steps:

$./config ; make ; make install

and compile Intel Engine :

$ make

Following the instruction in the README file,

```
env OPENSSL_ENGINES=`pwd` openssl speed -engine intel-accel -evp rc4
```

We got errors :

```
# env OPENSSL_ENGINES=`pwd` openssl speed -engine intel-accel -evp rc4
invalid engine "intel-accel"
140473186604712:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(/home/xxxxx/intel-accel-1.5/libintel-accel.so): /home/xxxxx/intel-accel-1.5/libintel-accel.so: undefined symbol: RSA_sign
140473186604712:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
140473186604712:error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:eng_dyn.c:450:
140473186604712:error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:eng_list.c:417:id=intel-accel
140473186604712:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libintel-accel.so): libintel-accel.so: undefined symbol: RSA_sign
140473186604712:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
140473186604712:error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:eng_dyn.c:450:
```

Is there any suggestions?